# primeng dropdown label width

Tags: css, angular, primeng, angular9, primeng-dropdowns

I use a **primeng dropdown** input and I want to make the div that holds the label placeholder to have 100% width. 
Here is how I use it:

```
<div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-fluid">
    <div class="ui-grid-row">
        <div class="ui-grid-col-2">
            <p-dropdown [options]="solutionsDropDownData" [(ngModel)]="solutionDropDownValue" placeholder="Solution..."
                [filter]="true" (onChange)="onSolutionChange($event)">
            </p-dropdown>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

***The problem is that I get a space after the placeholder while I want the placeholder to be full width***. The space can be seen below:
[image: white space width after placeholder 1]

When I choose an other value, with smaller length for example, the width of the space changes, it becomes bigger if I used the same example.
[image: white space width after placeholder 2]

I already tried this approaches, but none of them worked:

1. used **autoWidth** parameter, but this one gives me `Can't bind to 'autoWidth' since it isn't a known property of 'p-dropdown'.` error if I use it with brackets; the error disappears if I use it without brackets, but it doesn't work (I mention that **I imported the DropdownModule**);
2. used css classes like below (I used them separately and both, alternatively):

   .ui-dropdown-label-container{
   width:100% !important;
   }

   .ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-panel {
   min-width: 100% !important;
   width: max-content;
   }
3. used style parameter.

Comment: plz remove all parent div or comment all parent div after check

Comment: I tried that. It is not working.

Comment: Have you tried the second approach using ViewEncapsulation by Angular?

Comment: Do you mean to use in my component ViewEncapsulation.None?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this by adding the code below: 
[image]

[image]

Basically, I just added the dropdown inside a div and changed the background color of the div that's containing it.

Answer (score 0):

It happens because of the stylesheet you using for PrimeNG. We experienced same visual problem and achieved that by adding below css class to styles.css

```
.ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-label-container {
    width: inherit !important;
}
```

Actually `inherit` calls for `100%`, I couldn't understand why it didn't work for you.